# Extract a link in the_content()

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to improve a bookmarks manager/theme I've built (http://bookmarkie.waterstreetgm.org).

Right now, each post is simply a link:

`<a href="http://tumblr.everlane.com/page/4">Everlane Tumblr</a>.` ie: that one single link is the entire content of `the_content()`.

Easy enough and works great. Next, I want to be able to get a screenshot of the site via WordPress.com's mShots.

Problem is, I can't seem to extract that link from `the_content()` and feed it into the `<img src="">`.

If that wasn't clear, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<img src="http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/the-link-extracted-from-the_content()/?w=1024" />
```

I've tried severalvariations on this:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$link = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $content, $match);
```

But I can't achieve the basic task of extracting that link from `the_content()`. At the moment, I simply get a formatted link output. I can't find a way to grab the url instead of grabbing the whole link.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `preg_match_all()` returns the number of matches or FALSE on errror, your link will be in the `$match` array not in `$link`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just looking in the wrong place:

```
php > $txt = '<a href="http://tumblr.everlane.com/page/4">Everlane Tumblr</a>';
php > $matches = array();
php > echo preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $txt, $matches);
1
php > print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://tumblr.everlane.com/page/4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )
)
```

Comment: So close! This seems to be outputting the href with the number 1 in front of it. Like this: 1http://google.com.  I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: Turns out that number '1' was a lesson in return vs echo. The 1 was being echoed, while what I wanted was to return it to hand it to another function. Thanks for the help with this one!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a link in the content area why don't you just put the URL in a custom field. Then you can construct the heading for the post and the tag for  screenshot image within your template.

Even better would be to create a custom post type that didn't have a title or content area and just a custom meta box with a field for the URL.

Comment: Yeah, I could/should do an of these. But I've got 500+ posts/links in my bookmark manager now from years ago.